# Using regular expression, How can I get the href url of an anchor tag that matches a particular class value such as foo?

Tags: regex

Can anyone help me with PHP regex (Regular Expression). I want to get all URLs that matches a certain attribute. The following example is, I want to get all href URLs that has a class of 'foo'.

```
<a title="foo" href="http://foo.com/" class="foo">Foo</a>
<a href="http://bar.com/" class="bar">Bar</a>
<a class="foo" title="foobar" href="http://foobar.com/">FooBar</a>
```

Result should be match the 2 URLs:

- `http://foo.com/`
- `http://foobar.com/`

I know this can be done easily using PHP packages such as DOM crawlers, but I want to use PHP RegEx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I'm sorry @alfasin it's not the same, but thank you for the input. Kerwin solve the issue. Thanks. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sN8lE9/2)

```
class="foo"[^>]*href="([^"]*)"[^>]*|href="([^"]*)"[^>]*class="foo"
```

`[^>]*`:match other attributes

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Kerwin :)